# Android CoverFlow display text instead of images

Tags: android, coverflow

In one of my app, I need to read text from database and show it to user. I thought of using Coverflow for this purpose. So can anyone here please let me know, is it possible to display text using CoverFlow instead of images? I am trying to produce the output which is something similar to [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/). As suggested, I convert the text into bitmap images and trying to display it. But I am getting the blank screen. Please see my code below

```
public class CoverFlowDemoActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CoverFlow coverFlow;
        coverFlow = new CoverFlow(this);

        coverFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        ImageAdapter coverImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        coverFlow.setAdapter(coverImageAdapter);

        coverImageAdapter.populateBitmapArray();

        coverFlow.setSpacing(-25);
        coverFlow.setSelection(4, true);
        coverFlow.setAnimationDuration(1000);

        setContentView(coverFlow);
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        int mGalleryItemBackground;
        private Context mContext;

        private Bitmap[] bitmapImages;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
            bitmapImages = new Bitmap[9];
        }

        public void populateBitmapArray() {

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                Bitmap originalImage = textAsBitmap("Example Test", 50f,
                        R.color.red);
                bitmapImages[i] = originalImage;
            }

        }

        public int getCount() {
            return 9;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // Use this code if you want to load from resources
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
            i.setImageBitmap(bitmapImages[position]);
            i.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(130, 130));
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

            // Make sure we set anti-aliasing otherwise we get jaggies
            BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) i.getDrawable();
            drawable.setAntiAlias(true);

            return i;

            // return mImages[position];
        }

        /**
         * Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views depending on the
         * 'offset' to the center.
         */
        public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
            /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */
            return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float) Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));
        }

        public Bitmap textAsBitmap(String text, float largest, int textColor) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setTextSize(largest);
            paint.setColor(textColor);
            // int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + 0.5f); // round

            int width = 500;

            float baseline = (int) (paint.ascent() + 0.5f) + 3f;
            // int height = (int) ((baseline + paint.descent() + 0.5f) + 3);

            int height = 500;
            Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
            canvas.drawText(text, 0, baseline, paint);
            return image;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the gallery widget? If so, you can easily draw your text into a bitmap and display it with that. (look into Canvas.drawText())

Comment: I think you're talking about something like [THIS](http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/), but you should be clear about that in your OP rather than having us guess. Some people don't know what the `CoverFlow` widget is.

Comment: @aneal yes. I am trying to produce output similar to that video.

Comment: @Renard As suggested by you, I have converted text into bitmap images. But still I am getting blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

I had been doing something similar to yours. And I realise that you are drawing outside of your image.

To solve the problem, just change "baseline" to "250" and you will see your text as image.

e.g.:

CHANGE

```
canvas.drawText(text, 0, baseline, paint);
```

TO

```
canvas.drawText(text, 0, 250, paint);
```

Hope that this will be helpful to you

Comment: Sure. If you face any problem just let me know. Cos I had tried your code and after editing it works! ^o-